# cakephp how do you order by a count field?

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, orm, sql-order-by

I tried the following, but wasn't able to get it to sort.

```
$options = array(
                         'limit'  => $limit,
                         'offset' => $this->Account->get_offset($page, $limit),
                         'fields' => array(
                                           'Accounts.login', 
                                           'Accounts.name', 
                                           'Accounts.created', 
                                           'COUNT(DISTINCT(Buyer.id)) AS "Accounts__buyer_count"', 
                                           'COUNT(DISTINCT(Seller.id)) AS "Accounts__seller_count"', 
                                           'COUNT(DISTINCT(Certificate.id)) AS "Accounts__certificate_count"'
                                    ),
                         'joins' => array(
                                          array(
                                                'table'      => 'buyers',
                                                'alias'      => 'Buyer',
                                                'type'       => 'LEFT',
                                                'conditions' => array('Buyer.account_id = Accounts.id')
                                          ),
                                          array(
                                                'table'      => 'sellers',
                                                'alias'      => 'Seller',
                                                'type'       => 'LEFT',
                                                'conditions' => array('Seller.buyer_id = Buyer.id')
                                          ),
                                          array(
                                                'table'      => 'certificates',
                                                'alias'      => 'Certificate',
                                                'type'       => 'LEFT',
                                                'conditions' => array('Certificate.buyer_id = Buyer.id')
                                          )
                                    ),
                         'group' => array('Accounts.id'),
                         'order' => array('Accounts__certificate_count' => 'ASC')
        );
```

Comment: Use virtual fields as documented ( http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html ), then you can easily sort on them as well.

Comment: this is just a report, so it will not be used very often. If I add virtualfields then I dont know how will play out with my model relationships.

Comment: I think virtualfields are nice, but if they depend on other models then there's really no benefit.

Comment: I dont think you understand virtual fields, they can also be added ad-hock on demand just prior to the actual save call. that will make them temporarily attached and thus not mess with anything. Whenever using non table fields, virtual fields are the way to go. The result would pretty much be the same than yours, but "more cakish".

Comment: oh ok. Just did a trial run and works fine!!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Should go to MODEL and add

```
var $virtualFields = array(
    'buyer_count'       => 'COUNT(DISTINCT(Buyer.id))',
    'seller_count'      => 'COUNT(DISTINCT(Seller.id))',
    'certificate_count' => 'COUNT(DISTINCT(Certificate.id))',
);
```

After that you can sort the same other fields in table